# how can I convert this ternary into a if/else?

Tags: javascript

```
const mWeight = model && !pToolCat === 3 ? null : model && pToolCat === 3 && !pToolItems.length ? null : model && pToolCat === 3  && pToolItems.length ? pToolWeight() : null;
```

How can I turn this into a if else statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't do extra checks

```
var mWeight; 
if(model && pToolCat === 3 && pToolItems.length){ // check this one only
  mWeight = pToolWeight()
} else {
 mWeight = null; // else null anyway
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By your way of repeated conditions

```
const mWeight;
if(model && !pToolCat === 3 )
mWeight=null;
else if(model && pToolCat === 3 && !pToolItems.length)
mWeight=null;
else if(model && pToolCat === 3  && pToolItems.length)
mWeight=pToolWeight();
else
mWeight=null;
```

But that is waste of time. Use simple coding always

```
const mWeight;
if(model && pToolCat === 3 && pToolItems.length)
mWeight = pToolWeight();
else
mWeight = null;
```